# how to parse json from server response?

Tags: ios, xml, json, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking for web API calls.
i am able to call the API and able to receive the response from server.
but m not able to parse the json.

following is the response from server:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

{ "ExistsInDB": "False", "CanSave": "True", "EntityName": "ACCOUNT", "TypeDescription":   
  "Company", "TypePluralDescription": "Companies", "RequiredProperties": 
  "SalesAchiever.Data.SAQueryFieldSet", "MetaData": "", "ReadOnly": "False", "ACCTNAME":
  "", "AREA_ID": "", "ACCT_TYPE_ID": "", "ADDR1": "", "ADDR2": "", "ADDR3": "", "TOWN":
  "", "COUNTY": "", "POSTCODE": "", "COUNTRY": "", "TEL": "", "FAX": "", "EMAILORWEB": 
  "", "BUYGRP_ID": "", "STATUS": "", "SIC_CODE_ID": "", "CURRENCY_ID": "", "CALL_FREQ":
  "0", "DORMANT": "False", "CREATOR_ID": "", "CREATED_ON": "01/01/0001 00:00:00", 
  "LAST_EDITOR_ID": "", "LAST_EDITED": "01/01/0001 00:00:00", "LAST_ACTION_BY": "", 
  "LAST_ACTION": "01/01/0001 00:00:00", "NEXT_ACTION_BY": "" }
</string>
```

my problem is i am able to fetch the response from server.But the response contains some header file. i.e `<string>....data</string>`.

**I want to remove that header file from the response and save into NSDictionary**

can any one please help me out with this?
i am new to this platform.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show what AFNetworking code you currently have. Why is the server returning JSON wrapped in XML?

Comment: Possibly, you missed to set the "Accept" header in the request: `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: Why do u set it to accept html if you want json?

Comment: bcoz previously i have set the header file as:
  [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

so the app was crashing Stating:AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016

Answer (score 0):

Add the header file in the server:

For example, if you are using PHP, add this:

> header('Content-Type: application/json');